# Can't save indexPath.row to NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsuserdefaults, nsindexpath

I'm trying to save my tableview's rows that can be moved (indexPath.row) to NSUserdefaults but i'm out of success, it doesn't work or the app craches..
Whats's missing/wrong?

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
    {
        NSString *stringToMove = self.objects[sourceIndexPath.row];
        [self.objects removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
        [self.objects insertObject:stringToMove atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];


    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        //save indexPath 
        NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        int index = indexPath.row;
        [userDefaults setInteger:index forKey:@"saverows"];
        [userDefaults synchronize];

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        //load indexPath
        NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSInteger loadrows = [userDefaults integerForKey:@"saverows"];
        NSIndexPath *newIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:loadrows];
        self.objects[indexPath.row]=newIndex;

        //rows
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.textLabel.text=self.objects[indexPath.row];
        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)"
crashes at Thread 1: signal SIGABRT.
But it doesn't matter, I know my code is wrong, if I remove the NSuserdefault's codes it works fine.

Comment: It matters. The exceptions comes with a reason. Can you post the whole crash log?

Comment: Agree with @akashivskyy. The entire crash log is needed. And I'm not entirely sure about this... but when you call `setInteger:` on NSUserDefaults, it might need to be an ObjC Object, **not** a primitive data type like `int`. Try converting it to `NSInteger` or `NSNumber` first.

Comment: @Sam No, `-[NSUserDefaults setInteger:forKey:]` accepts an `NSInteger`.

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` has specific setters/getters for many primitive types including int.

Comment: Don't use NSUserDefaults as global storage. The name pretty much says it all: User Defaults.

Comment: @Sam NSInteger is an `int` (or a `long` on 64-bit cpus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to add `NSIndexPath` as a text for the UILabel

You can't do this

```
NSIndexPath *newIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:loadrows];
self.objects[indexPath.row]=newIndex;
```

Then doing this

```
cell.textLabel.text=self.objects[indexPath.row];
```

In the first part you are adding an NSIndexPath and then treating it as NSString and add it to the UILabel.

---

## Update 1

To Save the order of the cells you can save the entire array (since it is array of strings)

In `moveRowAtIndexPath:` method add this at the end

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:self.objects forKey:@"saverows"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

- Remove what you are doing under `save indexPath` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method
- Remove What you are doing under `load indexPath` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

In `viewDidLoad` method add the following

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
self.objects = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"saverows"];
```

Comment: You have already saved the indexPath in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method what are you trying to do in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: well load it back, when i restart the app the order of the rows should be the same.

Comment: order of what? ... You are saving only one indexPath which the user click on it ... What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The user is able to re-order the rows in the tableview, it works fine. But if I restart the app, the rows goes back to their original place. I want it to save the location of the rows. (only one section)

Comment: @Tibbe That's a totally different problem than the question you asked.

Comment: really? I said that they could be moved. But i'm sorry, I'm new to this. Thought that indexPath.row was relevant. So is there an answer to my new question?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's almost working! but the tableview loads empty rows if you haven't moved them before implementing the code in viewDidLoad. something is missing!

Comment: I figured out by also saving the objects the first time the app launches! thanks @HaniIbrahim!

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use these codes to save/load NSIndexPath...

   ```
   // NSUserDefaults+Extension.h
   @interface NSUserDefaults (Extension)
   - (void)setIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)value forKey:(NSString *)defaultName;
   - (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForKey:(NSString *)defaultName;
   @end
   ```

   Another file...

   ```
   // NSUserDefaults+Extension.m
   @implementation NSUserDefaults (Extension)
   - (void)setIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)value forKey:(NSString *)defaultName
   {
       [self setObject:@{@"row": @(value.row),
                         @"section": @(value.section)}
                forKey:defaultName];
   }
   - (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForKey:(NSString *)defaultName
   {
       NSDictionary *dict = [self objectForKey:defaultName];
       return [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[dict[@"row"] integerValue]
                                 inSection:[dict[@"section"] integerValue]];
   }
   @end
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   #import "NSUserDefaults+Extension.h"

   void someFun() {
       NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:55 inSection:99];
       NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
       [standardUserDefaults setIndexPath:path forKey:@"myKey"];
       [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
       NSLog(@"%@", [standardUserDefaults indexPathForKey:@"myKey"]);
   }
   ```
2. Your line `int index = indexPath.row;` should use `NSInteger` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you possible performance issues

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

You are getting the dequeue and then just overwriting it with a new cell.

```
if(cell)
  cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

should clear that up.